# Radio group setOnCheckedChangeListener that can work with selected radio as well

Tags: android, radio-group

I am using `.setOnCheckedChangeListener` to check a change on Radio group with three buttons. as per name it will detect if a change in radio buttons is detected. Hence clicking on the already selected item wont invoke anything.

is there any alternative that will work even for the selected radio , ignoring that it is already selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a bit confusing. But as far as I understood, `onCheckedChanged` fires automatically when your activity is loaded first time provided that you have set listener in `onCreate` method.

You can implement on `onClick` but then you have to take care of both events. As `onClick` will fire first and then `onCheckedChange` will fire. And in `OnCheckedChange` you can detect whether the Radio button changed or not by using a temporary variable.

Hope this answers your question.